# ColdFusion 9/10 return fromat JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, coldfusion, cffunction

I have some data that I have to return after the Ajax call. On my `.cfc` page I have the logic that converts the data. Each column is tab delimited and each row is separated with CRLR. I have my `cffunction` returnformat set to `JSON`. After I return the data I use JavaScript to separate columns and rows in desired format. While I was doing this I saw few blogs where people were talking about all kind of problems with `JSON` in ColdFusion 9. On my development site I use ColdFusion 10 and I haven't notice any problem in my data. But on the live site I have ColdFusion 9 and I was wondering if that will cause some problems. In my data I have fields like Address and this field allows all kind of characters. Return type JSON in coldfusion 9 has the problem if your data is like this for example `2131231D` if combination of strings and integers ends with `D` JSON will not return the same data. So my question is what I should do in this situation? Is there any fix for this problem? Is JSON reliable and  recommended to use in ColdFusion 9? I was looking also for some tool that will convert my data on .cfc page that way I can avoid `cffunction returnformat='JSON'`. Here is my code:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="getData" access="remote" output="true" returnformat="JSON">
        <cfset fncResults = StructNew()>

        <cfif myFile = true>
            <cfoutput query="myData">
                //Here I organize my data
            </cfoutput>

            <cfset getList = arrayToList(buffer,crlf)/> 
            <cfset fncResults.status = "200">
            <cfset fncResults.fileData = #getList#>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset fncResults.status = "400">
            <cfset fncResults.message = "The file was not properly uploaded.">
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn fncResults>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function getFile(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Components/test.cfc?method=getData',
    data: new FormData($('#myForm')[0]),
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json'
 }).done(function(obj){
    if(obj.STATUS === 200){
        return obj.FILEDATA;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
 }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(errorThrown);
 });
}
```

Comment: I haven't run into the problem your describing, but if you do, you could always switch to using the json cfc. Why are you using CF10 in dev if you have CF9 in production?

Comment: @KevinB Do you have any example of json cfc.? It's a lot of problems in the system and we were getting an errors when we tried to update live site to 10.

Comment: What seems odd to me is you're returning tab delimited data from your function.... i didn't know coldfusion would be able to convert that automagically to useful json. Unless it's just turning it into a string, in which case you likely won't have much to worry about.

Comment: What kind of errors? you aren't really json encoding your string at all, you're returning it as a property of `result` as a string, which means it'l just be a big string in the json response, it shouldn't get messed with other than escaping quotes.

Comment: @KevinB so far on ColdFusion 10 I did not have any problems with the data. I'm wondering if this will change in ColdFusion 9. I would like to prevent that before I role the code to live.

Comment: Spin up a dev CF9 dev server and test it. that's the only way to be sure.

Comment: The only problems I've run into with CF and JSON has to do with implicit conversion sometimes, mainly dealing with `bigint`. Trying to force something to be a string can be difficult if CF wants to make it a number.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your development and production environments as similar as possible to each other is a best practice. It reduces these kinds of "gotchas" when you push code to Production.

ColdFusion 10's JSON serializer/deserializer is vastly improved over CF9's. If you're working with a lot of JSON, then upgrading to CF10 on Production is a good idea. Until that's a possibility, using a separate serializer can help.

I suspect the "json cfc" that @KevinB mentioned [Ben Nadel's JsonSerializer.cfc](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2505-jsonserializer-cfc---a-data-serialization-utility-for-coldfusion.htm). It's available on Github (forked version, with a few extra features) at https://github.com/kevindb/JsonSerializer.cfc